# Find volume, given $V =\{(x,y,z) | x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \le 4 , x^2 + y^2 \ge 1 \}$

Tags: calculus, integration

$V =\{(x,y,z) | x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \le 4 , x^2 + y^2 \ge 1 \}$

[image]

I don't understand how they found the second angle, $z^2 = 3$, so $z = \sqrt3, -\sqrt3$? and even if so, why is it 150 degrees? the tan operations jumps $\pi k$ degrees. so shouldn't it be like $30$ degrees + $180$ degrees = $210$ degrees?

Comment: I am unclear what the angle is supposed to be in the diagram.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have $\;|z|=\sqrt3\;$, so if you put $\;x=0\;$, the intersection point between the plane $\;z=\sqrt3\;$ and the sphere is $\;v:=(0,1,\sqrt3)\;$. To know the azimut angle now calculate the angle between the above vector and $\;u:=(0,0,\sqrt3)\;$ :

$$\cos\alpha=\frac{\langle v,u\rangle}{\left\|v\right\|\,\left\|u\right\|}=\frac3{2\sqrt3}=\frac{\sqrt3}2\implies\alpha=\frac\pi6\;\;\left(\text{or}\;\;30^\circ\right)$$

Likewise with the intersection with $\;z=-\sqrt3\;$ you'll get $\;\alpha=\cfrac{5\pi}6\;\;(\text{or}\;\;150^\circ)\;$

Comment: Welcome BACK dear Don

Comment: @BabakS. Thank you very much, dear Babak. Just for little whiles here and there, but happy to meet you again, my friend.

Comment: Thank you Don! You always have to take x=0 because we are talking on $yz$ plane when finding the angle of $/phi$?

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS Not necessarily, but it is always important to have a *plane* that is perpendicular to the plane $\;z=;$ to check the azimut angle along it. In this case, one of the most usually used and comfortable planes is $\;x=0\;$